# PHP / Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) - Delete duplicate values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a website where I'm showing a list of bookmarks with multiple tags on each one, this is the output:

```
Bookmark Title
Link
Description text
#tag1 #tag2 #tag3 #tag4 #tag5

Bookmark Title
Link
Description text
#tag3 #tag4

Bookmark Title
Link
Description text
#tag1

(…)
```

I have a filter where I can select the tags to hide/show the corresponding bookmarks. The problem is now, when there a bookmarks with same tags, the tags also repeating in the filter like:

```
Filter: #tag1 #tag2 #tag3 #tag4 #tag5 #tag3 #tag4 #tag1
```

This is my filter:

```
<div class="d-headline--update__filter">
        <?php if( have_rows('bookmark', 'option') ):?>
            Filter:
            <span class="filter__item filter__all active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</span>
            <?php while( have_rows('bookmark', 'option') ) : the_row();?>
                            <?php $bookmarkTags = get_sub_field('bookmark_tags', 'option');
                            if( $bookmarkTags ): ?>
                                <?php foreach( $bookmarkTags as $bookmarkTag ): ?>
                                    <span onclick="filterSelection('<?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?>')" class="filter__item filter__<?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?>"><?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?></span>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

How can I delete the duplicates in the filter?

Comment: so if you have three bookmarks all in say `$tag1` you would see `$tag1` three times in your filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the tags you already displayed then conditionally display the tags if they are not already tracked.  See below for one way you might do this:

```
<div class="d-headline--update__filter">
  <?php if( have_rows('bookmark', 'option') ):?>
    Filter:
    <span class="filter__item filter__all active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">
      Show all
    </span>

    <?php 
    
    // collection of tags for this page
    $bookmarkTagsCollection = [];
    
    while( have_rows('bookmark', 'option') ) : the_row();?>
      <?php $bookmarkTags = get_sub_field('bookmark_tags', 'option'); ?> 
      
      <?php if ( $bookmarkTags ) : ?>

        <?php foreach( $bookmarkTags as $bookmarkTag ): ?>

          <?php // only display if this tag has not been displayed yet ?>

          <?php if (!in_array($bookmarkTag, $bookmarkTagsCollection)) : ?>
            <span onclick="filterSelection('<?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?>')" class="filter__item filter__<?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?>">
              <?php echo $bookmarkTag; ?>
            </span>

            <?php 
              // add current tag to collection to it does not get displayed again if later posts also contain this tag
              $bookmarkTagsCollection[] = $bookmarkTag;
            ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```